# writing to a file, but not just at the end

Tags: java

I want to write something to a file line by line.
I have the problem, that this process takes a lot of time and get canceld sometimes. The current version write the stuff to the file just at the end. Is it possible to write it to the file line by line?

E.g. if I abboard after line 4 (of 400) the file currently is empty. But I want to have the 4 line already in the file.

Here is my code:

```
String path = args[0];
String filename = args[1];

BufferedReader bufRdr = // this does not matter

BufferedWriter out = null;
FileWriter fstream;
try {
    fstream = new FileWriter(path + "Temp_" + filename);
    out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}

String line = null;

try {
    while ((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null) {            
        // HERE I'm doing the writing with out.write
        out.write(...);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}

try {
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: flush the stream to save the content to file. Though it is not recommended to keep on flushing the stream. Better is set a threshold of lines ( say after every 50lines ), flush after that point.

Comment: On another note,If you have already not noted it, bufRdr need to be initialized before being used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the flush function when you want to make sure the data that is already been written to the writer gets into the file

```
out.flush()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `out.flush()` after `out.write(...)`

Answer (score 2):

Use `out.flush()` after calling `out.write(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the java documentation [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html), you can directly write things to a file using the FileWriter, without using a BufferedWriter.

Also, as pointed out, you need to flush your datas before closing your buffer. The function `write` only fill your buffer, but it doesn't write to the file on the disk. This operation is done by using `flush` or `close` (to write the current content of the buffer to the disk). The difference between these two functions is that `flush` let's you write things after and `close` closes the stream definitely.

Answer (score 1):

The data you write to the buffer normally will not actually be written until out.flush() or out.close() is closed. so for your requirement you should use out.flush();